# How to implement tensor multiplication of a sparse matrix with a 3D tensor in TensorFlow2.0?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication, einsum

I have a sparse matrix A of shape (60400, 32600) and a 3D tensor B of shape (32600, 60400, 64). What I want to do is to multiply A and B to get a tensor C of shape (60400, 60400, 64), then generate the final tensor of shape (60400, 64) which has the diagonal elements of C.

I tried tf.sparse.sparse_dense_matmul(A, B) to get the tensor C first, but I got the ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3.

Then I used tf.einsum('ij, jik->ik', A, B) but I got the TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'inputs' of 'Einsum' Op have types [NOT CONVERTIBLE TO TENSOR, float32] that don't all match. I think this is because A is a sparse matrix, but I can't convert A from a sparse matrix to a dense matrix.

Any thoughts about this? I would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help you with the Tensorflow calculations directly, but can make some obsevations based on `numpy` and `scipy.sparse`.

`scipy.sparse` matrices are limited to 2d.  Recent versions make sparse arrays, but they are still limited to 2d.

Sparse 2d `matmul` with a dense is also limited to 2d dense arrays.  And the result is itself dense.  It's only sparse with sparse that produces a sparse result.  So even if sparse with 3d dense works, the  (60400, 60400, 64) would be too large of a dense tensor.  Also taking the diagonal of that throws out a whole lot values.

`numpy` einsum` does not work with sparse arrays.

```
 einsum('ij, jik->ik', A, B)
```

suggests that if `B` can be rearranged to `ijk` you could treat `i` as a match dimension.  With `matmul` you could do

```
'i1j, ijk -> i1k'  (last j of A with 2nd to last j of B)
```

So you could iterate on the `i` dimension of A and B, doing a matmul of A[i,:] (1d) and B[:,i,:] (2d).  But since the last dimension of B, 64, is relatively small, maybe you could iterate on that.

Anyways, you may need to spend a lot more time reading the tensorflow docs about sparse.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to construct the dense matrix A and use the batch matrix multiplication in tf.einsum as you suggested. I tested my code on a smaller dataset where matrix A had the shape (6040, 3240). The method was fine, but I still got the OOM error. You're absolutely right. Maybe I shouldn't have utilised such a large matrix.